# Windows Form listview minimum column width

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have the application look like it stops the width at 50, but if the mouse is dragged further on and then let up, the width will be below:

```
private void ListView1_ColumnWidthChanging(object sender, ColumnWidthChangingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex ==0 & e.NewWidth <50)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

I cannot work out how to force the `ColumnWidthChanged` width to 50 if the `changed width = < 50`. I don't need to fix the column widths, as information will vary in length, but force a minimum width.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to change the Width *after* the user has finished dragging the column separator you can do this

```
private const int _minimumColumnWidth = 50;

private void ListView1_ColumnWidthChanged(object sender, ColumnWidthChangedEventArgs e)
{
     if (ListView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Width < _minimumColumnWidth)
     {
          ListView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Width = _minimumColumnWidth;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Better ListView](http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview) and [Better ListView Express](http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview-express) (free) components have some of such useful properties on column headers:

```
betterListView.Columns[0].MinimumWidth = 50;
```

There is also **MaximumWidth** and **AllowResize**.